# What is the analog of a uniform matroid when the ground set is not finite?

Tags: matroids

If $E$ is a finite set and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then the uniform matroid of rank $k$ is defined as the matroid generated by taking the collection of $k$ element subsets of $E$ as a basis. Is there an analog of this notion when $E$ is not finite?

Currently reading [this](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/papers/matroidaxioms.pdf) paper, other references or examples would be great.

Comment: Browsing the Wikipedia article suggests that there does not seem to be an agreed-upon definition of an infinite matroid. What definition are you using?

Comment: @Qiaochu: The purpose of the cited paper is to *give* an axiomatic definition of infinitary matroids with duality; it actually gives five equivalent definitions, in terms of independent sets, bases, closure, circuits, and rank. It turns out that cardinality is too crude a measure, so a notion of relative rank is used that reduces to the usual notion in the finite case.

Answer (score 1):

An uniform matroid is a matroid such that: $\forall I\in \mathcal{I}$, $\forall x\in I$, $\forall y\in E\backslash I$, $I-x+y\in \mathcal{I}$.
Here some slides of a talk about the implications of the existance of infinite uniform matroids, http://settheory.mathtalks.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Geschke.pdf

Comment: The link no longer exists.